# Create form for service in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, service

[image: I'm trying to create the form from my service, however is giving this error]

this is the code excerpt in the controller

```
$service = $this->get('questions_service');
$form_question = $service->createQuestionForm($question, $this->generateUrl('create_question', array('adId' => $ad->getId())));
```

this is my function in service

```
public function createQuestionForm($entity, $route)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new QuestionType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $route,
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    $form
        ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => '>', 'attr' => array('class' => 'button button-question button-message')));

    return $form;
}
```

Comment: `createForm` is a shortcut method defined in `Controller` class that your controllers extend. Your service does not contain such a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `createForm()` function is an alias in [Symfony's Controller class](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php).  You will not have access to it from within your service.  You'll want to either inject the Symfony container into your service or inject the `form.factory` service.  For example:

```
services:
    questions_service:
        class:        AppBundle\Service\QuestionsService
        arguments:    [form.factory]
```

and then in your class:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory;

class QuestionsService
{
    private $formFactory;

    public function __construct(FormFactory $formFactory)
    {
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
    }

    public function createQuestionForm($entity, $route)
    {
        $form = $this->formFactory->createForm(new QuestionType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $route,
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

        $form
            ->add('submit', 'submit', array(
                'label' => '>',
                'attr' => array('class' => 'button button-question button-message')
        ));

        return $form;
    }
```

Comment: Please note that from Symfony 2.8 ``...->createForm(QuestionType::class, $entity...`` is preferred. The option to instantiate the class in the createForm call is removed in Symfony 3.x. Adding form fields by type name is deprecated as well. Use for instance ``SubmitType::class`` instead of ``'submit'`` when using Symfony 3.x